Random failure when converting a Revit model to SVF
We have a Revit model form one of our customer who failed to be converted to SVF by the APS Model Derivative API (model is uploaded to a temporary bucket, then SVF conversion is triggered and monitored by our web app).
The message received in case of failure was:
We have encountered some issues while preparing the file for viewing. Please contact support for assistance. Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741831
This error occurred twice last week amongst other successful attempts. But now, it seems all conversions are successful and can not reproduce the failure anymore (we were trying to get a test case for support).
Questions:
1- what is the meaning of "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741831"?
2- should we expect this error to still occur in the future?
Thanks,
Stephane

Please share a non-confidential reproducible sample with us through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com. This issue can happen due to a specific component of the design. You can also try opening this file in Revit and see if it is corrupt or any error appears.

Thanks @JoãoMartins.
Revit 2023 is reporting the following errors (all for the same specific family):

6x "Base sketch for extrusion is invalid" Error Resolution: Delete Instance(s)"
6x "Can't make Extrusion." Error Resolution: Delete Element(s)"
"6x Line is too short." Error Resolution: Delete Element(s)"
+1 warning: "Thickness of this Floor may be slightly inaccurate due to extreme Shape Editing..."
All errors are reported as automatically resolved.
Unfortunately, our customer who is trying to import this model in our app did not allow us to share the model with any 3rd party.

